# Check today date greater than in if condition in aggregate mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to check offer expiry date is greater than today if yes then return yes else no
I have done below code but it's not working as per requirement 
Please help me.

```
Offer.aggregate([ 
    enddate: {
            $cond: { 
             if: {  
                  $gte: [new Date(new Date().getTime()-60*5*1000).toISOString(),true] 
                  },
             then: "No",
             else: "Yes"}
        },
]);
```

Comment: $ gte compares two values and returns:  
1.true when the first value is greater than or equivalent to the second value.
2.false when the first value is less than the second value.  

example : $gte :{ new Date() , "$exiprydatefield"]

Comment: ` enddate: {
            $cond: { if: {  $gte: [new Date(),'$enddate'] },then: "Yes",else: "No"}
        },` 

I have change query and it's working

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) and for the condition the correct syntax is `if: { $gt: ["$enddate", new Date()] }` where `enddate` is the field you want to check:

```
Offer.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      isExpired: { // new field
        $cond: { 
           if: { $gt: ["$enddate", new Date()] },
           then: "No",
           else: "Yes"
        }
      },
    } 
  } 
]);
```

More about `$cond`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/